# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse hangs on response with no content

Tags: .net, http, httpwebresponse

I've written a small "web server" that replays a pre-crafted response to everything. In this case:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n
\r\n
```

The following client code hangs until the TCP timeout kicks in:

```
using (WebResponse response = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse()) { }
```

I've spied on the conversation with Wireshark, and all the data gets sent and received properly. `GetResponse` keeps waiting after receiving the response quoted above. But it shouldn't - it's a valid HTTP response, right? What's wrong?

When I add any content to the response, everything works as expected.

Comment: Is your web server then closing the connection, or leaving it open? Without a Content-Length header, it may well be waiting to you to close the connection. You could try adding `Content-Length: 0` to your response.

Comment: Okay, so how is the client meant to know that you're not sending any content?

Comment: Because the response has no Content-Type nor Content-Length headers?

Comment: I don't think the absence of a Content-Length header is equivalent to a length of 0. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4 doesn't cover your response, as far as I can tell. It would *at least* be friendlier to specify a content length of 0 - and it's at least worth a try.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks! Put it in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the client is getting confused by the lack of a `Content-Length` header - it doesn't know how much content it might receive, so it's waiting for the server to close the connection, which *also* isn't happening.

Try adding

```
Content-Length: 0
```

to the response headers.

Comment: The client is also correct to act like this according to the RFC: All responses to the HEAD request method MUST NOT include a message-body, even though the presence of entity- header fields might lead one to believe they do. All 1xx (informational), 204 (no content), and 304 (not modified) responses MUST NOT include a message-body. **All other responses do include a message-body, although it MAY be of zero length.**